# Programming game intro animation

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I'm working on a game on Pygame and was trying to implement the game intro. I want to have two characters moving around and talking, with the player needing to press space to move the dialogue forward and let the intro animation continue.

Although I have no problems moving the main character across the screen while in the main game loop (using keys as inputs), implementing the intro "animation" is proving harder than what I thought.

My intention is for these two characters to walk to different places on the screen and stop while they talk. And then start walking again in a different direction, etc.

Below is the code I'm implementing now but it is not working as I expected, the game takes too long to load sometimes since I added this new part and also because it is not a cyclic movement (not a repetitive while loop as in my main game loop), but a rather defined series of events, I'm not sure how to approach it.

What I've been doing is calling a function called `intro` from the `main_loop` function (which is the one with my main While loop). I'm noticing that because I'm not running a repetitive loop, then the refreshing is not working correctly, and I have to call my update (or flip) display multiple times to avoid having the characters leaving the previous position in screen but it still happens anyway). Again, the whole thing is really slow.

```
def intro():

    #VARIABLES
    P1_x = 280 #starting position
    P1_y = 380 #starting position
    P1_dir = 3 #for the player sprite sheet loading
    NPC_x = 240
    NPC_y = 280
    NPC_dir = 2

    #LOAD PLAYER CLASSES
    P1 = player(P1_x, P1_y, P1_dir)
    P2 = npc(NPC_x, NPC_y, NPC_dir)

    gameDisplay.fill(black)

    #DRAW BACKGROUND MAP PLUS BACKGROUND OBJECTS
    draw_layer(intro_int_matrix, house_tiles, house_tiles_W, house_tiles_H)
    draw_layer_2(intro_int_matrix_2, intro_house_2, intro_house_2_W, intro_house_2_H)

    #LOOP (TRIED WITH "WHILE" ALSO) TO MAKE THE PLAYER MOVE A BIT IN A DIRECTION AND THEN STOP
    for i in range (5):
        P1.update(3, 0, P1_dir) #THE 3 IS THE DISTANCE TO MOVE IN X-AXIS, and 0 in Y axis
        pygame.display.update() 
        pygame.time.delay(300) #TRIED ADDING A DELAY SO IT DOES NOT MOVE TOO FAST BUT DOES NOT HELP MUCH

    #THE IDEA OF SETTING X AND Y TO 0 IS TO STOP THE MOVEMENT          
    P1.update(0, 0, P2_dir)
    draw_layer(intro_int_matrix, house_tiles, house_tiles_W, house_tiles_H)
    draw_layer_2(intro_int_matrix_2, intro_house_2, intro_house_2_W, intro_house_2_H)
    pygame.display.update() 
    pygame.time.delay(1000)

    #SHOW DIALOGUE....AND WAIT FOR "SPACE" INPUT

    #THEN I WILL INCLUDE ANOTHER "FOR" LOOP TO KEEP ON MOVING TO A DIFFERENT POSITION AND CALLING THE DIALOGUE IN BETWEEN ETC, BUT I WANT TO SOLVE THE MOVEMENT PART FIRST.
```

---

EDIT: I've managed to solve this problem by simply using a While loop in my def intro() and then inside use several IF statements that get triggered by two conditions: 1, the step number (which allows me to track the animation instance) and 2, the get_ticks() number, which allows me to control the pace of the animation. Then because of the While loop, everything repeats X amount of times by using additional IF statements inside the IF statement I just mentioned. Hopefully, this is easy to understand for anyone having this issue.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's good that you managed to solve it by yourself. As a Q&A site, you're allowed *and encouraged* to post your answer... on the answer box below. Remember, question box is for the question, answer box is for the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

A good rule of thumb when implementing movement into graphics is to use a LOT of really small steps, as opposed to a few, slow, large steps. So in your case you want to have a for loop that pauses for less time and moves the characters less per clock update. In example, I've edited your loop:

```
for i in range (15):
    P1.update(1, 0, P1_dir) #THE 3 IS THE DISTANCE TO MOVE IN X AXIS, and 0 
in Y axis
    pygame.display.update() 
    pygame.time.delay(100) #TRIED ADDING A DELAY SO IT DOES NOT MOVE TOO FAST BUT DOES NOT HELP MUCH
```

this makes it so instead of having 5 updates of 3 pixels, you have 15 updates of 1 pixel happening 3x as fast.

**Now to answer your question:** Pygame works when you have things in a for loop, so take a look at your code here:

```
P1.update(0, 0, P2_dir)
draw_layer(intro_int_matrix, house_tiles, house_tiles_W, house_tiles_H)
draw_layer_2(intro_int_matrix_2, intro_house_2, intro_house_2_W, 
intro_house_2_H)
pygame.display.update() 
pygame.time.delay(1000)
```

in your implementation, you do not have a loop that is running, you only call the draw functions a single time and then delay for 1 second. A correct implementation would be to wrap this in a for loop, so that the game will continually refresh while you do the dialog:

```
for i in range(300): # first dialog popup
    P1.update(0, 0, P2_dir)
    draw_layer(intro_int_matrix, house_tiles, house_tiles_W, house_tiles_H)
    draw_layer_2(intro_int_matrix_2, intro_house_2, intro_house_2_W, 
    intro_house_2_H)
    #implement 1st part of dialog
    pygame.display.update() 
    pygame.time.delay(10)

for i in range(300): # second dialog popup
    P1.update(0, 0, P2_dir)
    draw_layer(intro_int_matrix, house_tiles, house_tiles_W, house_tiles_H)
    draw_layer_2(intro_int_matrix_2, intro_house_2, intro_house_2_W, 
    intro_house_2_H)
    #implement 2nd part of dialog
    pygame.display.update() 
    pygame.time.delay(10)
```

Note how this loops.

Comment: I have tried changing my code to this but it keeps crushing. I don't get an error but when the game starts I just get a white screen and nothing happens. I need to investigate a bit more, but I think that maybe I should use While loops instead of for. Just a thought.